# ZeroMQ: is there a limitation for the amount of topics that SUBs can subscribe for?

Tags: python, c, zeromq, pyzmq

I am using the PUB/SUB socket pattern of ZeroMQ. The PUB produces stocks' financial data and publish them. The topic is set as each stock's code. At the SUB side, clients can subscribe for data which they want based on stock code. The PUB is written in C and the SUB is written in Python.

However, something goes wrong during testing. If only one stock code is set as a message filter on the SUB socket, everything works well. But when it comes to a large number of stocks, the program will crash in a short time, giving the error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" ( details follow below ).

Here is the code of **PUB (C)** :

```
while (1) {  
    int rc = 0;
    // send topic
    rc = zmq_send(pub_socket, topic, rc, ZMQ_SNDMORE);
    if (rc == -1) {
        // error handling
    }
    // send stock data
    rc = zmq_send(pub_socket, data, rc, 0);
    if (rc == -1) {
        // error handling
    }
}
```

Here is the code of **SUB (Python)**:

```
import zmq

# initialize a SUB socket
ctx = zmq.Context.instance()
socket = ctx.socket(zmq.SUB)

# set socket options to filter message
for code in code_list:
    socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, code)

socket.connect(PUB_ADDR)
# recv data from PUB
while True:
    data = socket.recv()
    print(data)
```

I also used gdb to debug the program. The **debug result** is like:
[debug result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nehdm.png)
   [image]

Does anyone know why the program crashes? Any help is welcome, thanks.

---

### **Update**:

If I replace the `setsockopt_string` part with the following code, the Python script works well. Strange thing... I need to dig deeper into the `setsockopt_string` function.

New code in **Python**:

```
socket.setsockopt_string( zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "" )
```

---

### **Latest Update**:

I ran the script provided by @user3666197 and got a debug log. I select only several parts of the log because it's very long.

Socket initialization
[image: Initialization]
setsockopt_string finished
[image: setsockopt_string finished]
recv one msg and exited
[image: recv one msg and exited]

Comment: Do you have the sources (`malloc.c`) on your machine? What do you see if you enter `list` after `bt`? How much memory does the machine have?

Comment: @Attie 1. it seems that i don't have malloc.c on my machine because i use `find` command to search the file and no result is returned; 2. i kind of having no idea about how to debug the problem, i will debug the program during tomorrow's trading period and update the `list` results; 3. the machine's memory is 32 GB

Comment: As the `SEGFAULT` is in malloc.c, I would suspect that there is some heap corruption. Might be worth getting the sources... What is your OS?
On Ubuntu, you can run: `apt-get install libc6-dev` (needs root, and substitute the correct package name). If you need more, you can run `apt-get source libc6` (doesn't need root). You can then locate `malloc.c:3588` and get a hint as to what's going wrong.

Comment: Might also be worth looking into the python `gdb` extensions to see where the crash occurred in your python application... I've never had much luck with it, so you might need to get others to chip in. https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb / https://docs.python.org/devguide/gdb.html

Comment: What **version** of ZeroMQ do your PUB and SUB use? **How many SUB**s are .connect()-ed? How many **PUB-side** feeders are pumping the messages or how many messages are broadcast in your test per second?

Comment: @Attie i will have a try. Thanks

Comment: @user3666197 1. the version of SUB is 16.0.2 and PUB is 4.1.5; 2.  In testing case, there is only one PUB and one SUB; 3. I don't have a certain number of the messages sent per second, i guess the amount is about 3000.

Comment: Have you tried to **run** the mod-ed **isolation-test *( ref. below )*** and **do you plan to post the results from the there published trivial DEBUG:log**?

Comment: @user3666197 Sorry, some other things came up and distracted my attention. I modified the code structure of the PUB side and my finger got injured, so i haven't run the test script yet. I will update the DEBUG:log once i run the script, maybe 2 or 3 days later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Intro:

**`PUB`**-side uses ZeroMQ v 4.1.5;
**`SUB`**-side uses ZeroMQ Python wrapper 16.0.2

Implicitly this makes `PUB/SUB` pattern, being in contrast to previous generations of API back to v 2.0, to rely on a **`PUB`**-side filtering, whereas your **`SIGSEGV`** indication reports problem on `SUB`-side.

In spite of the said hypothesis that the filtering is the root-cause, I recall some technical debate about large-tree filtering issues, there still is one minor surprise, as in some post about Trie-search, the added **`""`** leaf-node also did a magic service. Will try to find this debate again, if it could help.

Initial [remarks from Martin Sustrik **refer up to**](http://nanomsg.org/documentation-zeromq.html) about ~10,000 subscriptions in ZeroMQ filter are not to make issues ( with some higher numbers under further design discussions ):

> **Efficient Subscription Matching**
>
> In ZeroMQ, simple tries are used to store and match `PUB/SUB` subscriptions. The subscription mechanism was intended for up to 10,000 subscriptions where simple trie works well. However, there are users who use as much as 150,000,000 subscriptions. In such cases there's a need for a more efficient data structure. Thus, nanomsg uses memory-efficient version of Patricia trie instead of simple trie.
>
> For more details check [**this article**](http://250bpm.com/blog:19).

---

### Diagnose the cause, always, using a step-by-step approach at least:

One slight test modification will bring you closer to open the problem's real envelope:

```
import zmq
pass;                                           print "DEBUG: Ok, zmq imported. [ver:{0:}]".format( zmq.pyzmq_version() )
#_______________________________________________# SETUP ZMQ:
ctx    = zmq.Context( 2 )                       # Context( nIOthreads )
pass;                                           print "DEBUG: Ok, zmq.Context() instantiated."  
socket = ctx.socket(  zmq.SUB )                 # Socket(  .SUB )
pass;                                           print "DEBUG: Ok, Socket instantiated."
socket.connect(           PUB_ADDR )            # .connect()
pass;                                           print "DEBUG: Ok, .connect() completed."
socket.setsockopt(   zmq.LINGER, 0 )            # explicit LINGER
pass;                                           print "DEBUG: Ok, .setsockopt( LINGER, 0 ) completed."
#_______________________________________________# SET FILTER:
for code in code_list:
    pass;                                       print "DEBUG: Going to set SUB side n-th filter: {0: > 1000d}. == [{1:}]".format( code_list.index( code ), repr( code ) ),
    socket.setsockopt_string( zmq.SUBSCRIBE, code )
    pass;                                       print "DEBUG: Ok, this one was done."
pass;                                           print "DEBUG: Ok, all items from <code_list> exhausted."
#_______________________________________________# LOOP FOREVER:
while True:
    try:
          print "LOOP: .recv() call."
          data = socket.recv()
          print "LOOP: .recv()-ed {0:}[B] repr()-ed as [{1:}]".format( len( data ), repr( data ) )

    except KeyboardInterrupt():
          print "EXC: Ctrl-C will terminate."

    except:
          print "EXC: will terminate."

    finally:
          pass;                                 print "DEBUG: Ok, finally: section entered:"
          socket.close()
          pass;                                 print "DEBUG: Ok, Socket instance .close() call returned"
          ctx.term()
          pass;                                 print "DEBUG: Ok, .Context() instance term()-ed"
          break
```

Given the testing case described as there was only one **`PUB`** and one **`SUB`**, the other performance scaling & detailed buffer management issues are not going to explode the problem at the moment. Will see the results, after you run the mod-ed test and post the trivial DEBUG:log.

Sending just about 3k messages per second shall not be an issue either.

---

### UPDATE: missed points -- (1) Unicode handling + (2) Topic-filter

**(1)** as seen in the DEBUG:log, you mix Unicode and plain C-byte arrays. [These **representations MUST match** - system-wide](http://pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/unicode.html#first-unicode-in-python-2-and-3) ( from `.send_string()`, via `.setsockopt_string()`, till `.recv_string()` )

```
data = socket.recv_string()           # AS YOUR DEBUG:log shows the b'mkt_bar...'
```

**(2)** Topic-**filters MUST match** - otherwise a message gets sorted out as a non-subscribed one ... so that u'abc ....' filter matches u'abc ....' messages. Not otherwise:

> `setsockopt_string( option, optval, encoding='utf-8' )`
>   
>   An empty **`optval`** of length zero shall subscribe to all incoming messages. A **non-empty `optval`** shall subscribe to **all messages beginning with the specified prefix.** Multiple filters may be attached to a single ZMQ_SUB socket, in which case a message shall be accepted if it matches at least one filter.

DEBUG:log fragments provided above show ( well, the PrintScreens ... -- please, next time **rather copy/paste terminal ASCII**, not pictures, unless showing some GUI features, right? Thx... ), that your topic-filters never match in the defined sense. Fix that. System-wide.

ZeroMQ is not to be blamed on this, Unicode + C-byte arrays simply cannot work and headbang, if mixed or if in wrong calling interfaces.

---

### Epilogue:

If still accusing ZeroMQ topic-filtering capacities, the simplest a/b-test to (dis)-approve the Null-hypothesis would be to run the VERY SAME test, but with just 5-topic-filter elements in place. If that crashes either, your hypothesis about capacity-related limitations was wrong.

Keep Walking!

Comment: I have posted the DEBUG:log. As the log shows, the program received one message and exited. According to the article above, ZeroMQ uses a memory-unefficient way to store message topics. In my case, the topic is something like "mkt_bars_min1 + code_name" and it seems topics like this will cost lots of memory. Is this the reason why the program will crash?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did pay little attention to Unicode handling, i will dig deeper into it. As you suggest -- run a test with **5-topic-filter** elements, i have tested the case in which **300-topic-filter** elements were applied and the program worked well.

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood my meaning. I tested the 300-topic-filter elements case the other days, but when the amount of topics raises to around 4000, the program will still crash, so my problem hasn't actually been solved. Still appreciate your help:)

Comment: So, could you confirm, that both the unicode/byte-array mismatch & the topic-filter / message non-matching ( both observed in the DEBUG:log ) was already corrected & you still experience runtime crashes? Could you update your post & add text copy of DEBUG:log?

Comment: I can't run the script now because the trading time is over. I will update the DEBUG:log once I run the test.

Comment: Aha, you run against a direct Exchange API, or is there any other 24/7/365 or Quant / backtesting API to run against?

Comment: Great idea. However, a situation needs to be brought up that I have an emergent task to work on these few days, so the update may be delayed. I will use backtesting data to test to speed up the process after the task is finished. Sorry about the delay and keep patient please :)